# Code is not displaying any answer when using function any() in python

Tags: python-3.x, any

I have searched  the official documentation and some tutorials. However my example is not working. The code is supposed to display "True".

def rocks():
    lista=[2,4, 6]
    any(lista)
    return True
    return False
rocks()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a formatting issue or if perhaps you've omitted the print function, but running the following works for me:

```
def rocks():
    lista = [2, 4, 6]
    return any(lista)

print(rocks())
```

Comment: It works, but if the list is empty it is supposed to display False. However, it is still displaying "True".

Comment: If I run the same code but with `lista = []` I get False. Can you maybe reproduce the bug here? https://repl.it/languages/python3

Comment: I did. Same results. I do not know if this issue is related to Anaconda and Spyder.

Comment: Can you share a link?

Comment: I see the issue - instead of `return True` you need to `return any()` as it is in my answer. The function as you've written it will always return True no matter what, because that's what you've returned. Check out this sample: https://repl.it/repls/HarmoniousGrouchyCode